# Derive Last PO Price in SQL Query (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am developing a script to get a list items by vendor and organization unit with their respective minimum, maximum, average and last price for a specific period of time (transaction date). The last price is based on the latest transaction date.

I am having some issues to calculate the last price based on the script I developed. I tried to

(1) Add an inner query to look for the maximum transaction date for an item, organization and vendor

(2) Based on the output do a join with the outer query and join on the item id, org id and vendor id.

But I am not getting the expected result.

Below is the query without the inner query to derive the last price.

```
SELECT NAME INVENTORY_ORG,SEGMENT1 CATEGORY_SEGMENT_1, SEGMENT2 CATEGORY_SEGMENT2, SEGMENT3 CATEGORY_SEGMENT_3,ITEM_DESCRIPTION ARTICLE, TRANSACTION_TYPE TYPE, VENDOR_NAME SUPPLIER,UNIT_OF_MEASURE UNIT,SUM(QUANTITY) QUANTITY_PURCHASED, AVG(PO_UNIT_PRICE) AVERAGE_PRICE, MIN(PO_UNIT_PRICE)MIN_PRICE, MAX(PO_UNIT_PRICE)MAX_PRICE, SUM(QUANTITY) * AVG(PO_UNIT_PRICE) NET_AMOUNT, SUM(VAT_AMOUNT) VAT_AMOUNT,((SUM(QUANTITY) * AVG(PO_UNIT_PRICE)) + SUM(VAT_AMOUNT)) GROSS_AMOUNT
FROM
(SELECT RCV.TRANSACTION_ID, MC.SEGMENT1, MC.SEGMENT2, MC.SEGMENT3,RCV.TRANSACTION_TYPE, RCV.TRANSACTION_DATE, PLA.ITEM_DESCRIPTION,RCV.QUANTITY, RCV.UNIT_OF_MEASURE, RCV.PO_UNIT_PRICE, RCV.ORGANIZATION_ID, HOU.NAME, APS.VENDOR_NAME,
case
WHEN msi.taxable_flag = 'N' then 0
ELSE (nvl(zrb.PERCENTAGE_RATE,0)/100) * PV.Unit_Price*RCV.quantity end as VAT_AMOUNT 
FROM 
RCV_TRANSACTIONS RCV, PO_LINES_ALL PLA, HR_ORGANIZATION_UNITS HOU, AP_SUPPLIERS APS, PO_LINES_REF_V PV, MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS MSI,ZX_RATES_B ZRB, MTL_ITEM_CATEGORIES MIC, MTL_CATEGORIES MC
WHERE TRUNC(RCV.TRANSACTION_DATE) >= NVL(:p_transaction_date_from, TRUNC(RCV.TRANSACTION_DATE))
AND  TRUNC(RCV.TRANSACTION_DATE) <= NVL(:p_transaction_date_to, TRUNC(RCV.TRANSACTION_DATE))
AND PLA.ITEM_DESCRIPTION = NVL(:p_item_description, PLA.ITEM_DESCRIPTION) 
AND RCV.ORGANIZATION_ID = NVL(:p_org_id,RCV.ORGANIZATION_ID)
AND APS.VENDOR_NAME = NVL(:p_supplier_name, APS.VENDOR_NAME)
AND RCV.PO_LINE_ID= PV.PO_LINE_ID
AND PLA.PO_LINE_ID(+) = RCV.PO_LINE_ID
AND HOU.ORGANIZATION_ID = RCV.ORGANIZATION_ID
and MSI.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = PLA.ITEM_ID
and MSI.ORGANIZATION_ID = RCV.ORGANIZATION_ID
AND MSI.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = MIC.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
AND MIC.CATEGORY_ID = MC.CATEGORY_ID
AND APS.VENDOR_ID(+) = RCV.VENDOR_ID
and ZRB.TAX_RATE_CODE (+)= msi.tax_code
AND RCV.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'RECEIVE'
AND MIC.CATEGORY_SET_ID = '1') 
GROUP BY TRANSACTION_TYPE, ITEM_DESCRIPTION, UNIT_OF_MEASURE, NAME, VENDOR_NAME, SEGMENT1, SEGMENT2, SEGMENT3
ORDER BY INVENTORY_ORG,ITEM_DESCRIPTION,VENDOR_NAME,SEGMENT1, SEGMENT2, SEGMENT3
```

The PO Unit Price is from the table RCV_Transactions. We get the Item ID from PO_Lines_all table.

Grateful if anyone can assist me and give me some tips on the best way to get the last price based on the above query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `last_value` function (oracle analytic function) see how https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions073.htm

```
SELECT LAST_VALUE(PO_UNIT_PRICE) over (order by trunc(RCV.TRANSACTION_DATE) ) ...
```

or if you need partitioned you can do this

```
SELECT LAST_VALUE(PO_UNIT_PRICE) over (partition by INVENTORY_ORG order by trunc(RCV.TRANSACTION_DATE) ) ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have include the last_value analytic function in an inner query and I am getting duplicates when running the script. Can you please indicate how to I adapt the analytic function in the above script?

Answer (score 0):

**Modified script using LAST_VALUE analytic function**

```
SELECT NAME INVENTORY_ORG,SEGMENT1 CATEGORY_SEGMENT_1, SEGMENT2 CATEGORY_SEGMENT2, SEGMENT3 CATEGORY_SEGMENT_3,ITEM_DESCRIPTION ARTICLE, TRANSACTION_TYPE TYPE, VENDOR_NAME SUPPLIER,UNIT_OF_MEASURE UNIT,SUM(QUANTITY) QUANTITY_PURCHASED, AVG(PO_UNIT_PRICE) AVERAGE_PRICE, MIN(PO_UNIT_PRICE)MIN_PRICE, MAX(PO_UNIT_PRICE)MAX_PRICE, SUM(QUANTITY) * AVG(PO_UNIT_PRICE) NET_AMOUNT, SUM(VAT_AMOUNT) VAT_AMOUNT,((SUM(QUANTITY) * AVG(PO_UNIT_PRICE)) + SUM(VAT_AMOUNT)) GROSS_AMOUNT, LAST_PO_PRICE
FROM
(SELECT 
RCV.TRANSACTION_ID, 
MC.SEGMENT1, 
MC.SEGMENT2, 
MC.SEGMENT3,
RCV.TRANSACTION_TYPE, 
RCV.TRANSACTION_DATE, 
PLA.ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
RCV.QUANTITY, 
RCV.UNIT_OF_MEASURE, 
RCV.PO_UNIT_PRICE, 
RCV.ORGANIZATION_ID, 
HOU.NAME,
APS.VENDOR_NAME,
case
WHEN msi.taxable_flag = 'N' then 0
ELSE (nvl(zrb.PERCENTAGE_RATE,0)/100) * PV.Unit_Price*RCV.quantity end as VAT_AMOUNT,
A.LAST_PO_PRICE 
FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT LAST_VALUE(RCV.PO_UNIT_PRICE) over (partition by RCV.ORGANIZATION_ID order by trunc(RCV.TRANSACTION_DATE) ) LAST_PO_PRICE, PLA.ITEM_ID,RCV.ORGANIZATION_ID, RCV.VENDOR_ID
FROM RCV_TRANSACTIONS RCV, PO_LINES_ALL PLA
WHERE PLA.PO_LINE_ID = RCV.PO_LINE_ID
ORDER BY PLA.ITEM_ID
)A,
RCV_TRANSACTIONS RCV, 
PO_LINES_ALL PLA, 
HR_ORGANIZATION_UNITS HOU,
AP_SUPPLIERS APS,
PO_LINES_REF_V PV,
MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS MSI,
ZX_RATES_B ZRB,
MTL_ITEM_CATEGORIES MIC, 
MTL_CATEGORIES MC
WHERE TRUNC(RCV.TRANSACTION_DATE) >= NVL(:p_transaction_date_from, TRUNC(RCV.TRANSACTION_DATE))
AND  TRUNC(RCV.TRANSACTION_DATE) <= NVL(:p_transaction_date_to, TRUNC(RCV.TRANSACTION_DATE))
/* Condition when no item description exist */
--AND (PLA.ITEM_DESCRIPTION = NVL(:p_item_description, PLA.ITEM_DESCRIPTION) OR PLA.ITEM_DESCRIPTION IS NULL)
--AND PLA.ITEM_DESCRIPTION = NVL(:p_item_description, PLA.ITEM_DESCRIPTION) 
AND A.ITEM_ID = PLA.ITEM_ID
AND A.ORGANIZATION_ID = RCV.ORGANIZATION_ID
AND A.VENDOR_ID = RCV.VENDOR_ID
AND RCV.ORGANIZATION_ID = NVL(:p_org_id,RCV.ORGANIZATION_ID)
AND APS.VENDOR_NAME = NVL(:p_supplier_name, APS.VENDOR_NAME)
AND RCV.PO_LINE_ID= PV.PO_LINE_ID
AND PLA.PO_LINE_ID(+) = RCV.PO_LINE_ID
AND HOU.ORGANIZATION_ID = RCV.ORGANIZATION_ID
and MSI.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = PLA.ITEM_ID
and MSI.ORGANIZATION_ID = RCV.ORGANIZATION_ID
AND MSI.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = MIC.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
AND MIC.ORGANIZATION_ID = RCV.ORGANIZATION_ID
AND MIC.CATEGORY_ID = MC.CATEGORY_ID
AND APS.VENDOR_ID(+) = RCV.VENDOR_ID
and ZRB.TAX_RATE_CODE (+)= msi.tax_code
AND RCV.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'RECEIVE'
AND MIC.CATEGORY_SET_ID = '1') 
GROUP BY TRANSACTION_TYPE, ITEM_DESCRIPTION, UNIT_OF_MEASURE, NAME, VENDOR_NAME, SEGMENT1, SEGMENT2, SEGMENT3, PO_UNIT_PRICE, TRANSACTION_DATE, LAST_PO_PRICE
ORDER BY INVENTORY_ORG,ITEM_DESCRIPTION,VENDOR_NAME,SEGMENT1, SEGMENT2, SEGMENT3
```

Comment: it's very big sql query and i can't check where is error exists, especialy whithout a real data and structure. i think no need create `A` , try add `LAST_VALUE(RCV.PO_UNIT_PRICE) over (partition by RCV.ORGANIZATION_ID order by trunc(RCV.TRANSACTION_DATE) ) LAST_PO_PRICE` in select statement of your big subquery before group by